# Julia - Iterating over combinations of keys in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, iterator, julia

Is there a nifty way to iterate over combinations of keys in a dictionary?

my dictionary has values like:

```
[1] => [1,2], [2,3] => [15], [3] => [6,7,8], [4,9,11] => [3], ...
```

what I need to do is fetch all combinations of keys that are of length `1:n` where `n` might be fx 3

So as in the example above, I would want to iterate over

```
[[1], [3], [2,3], [[1],[1,2]], [[3],[2,3]], [4,9,11]]
```

I know I could just collect the keys, but my dictionary is rather large and I am in the middle of redesigning the entire algorithm because it starts swapping insanely when `n > 3`, reducing efficiency terribly

**tl;dr** is there a way to create a combinatoric iterator from a dictionary without `collect`-ing the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a straight forward implementation, which tries to minimize a bit on going through the dictionary. Additionally it uses OrderedDict so holding key indices makes sense (since Dicts don't promise consistent key iteration each time and thus meaningful key indexing).

```
using Iterators
using DataStructures

od = OrderedDict([1] => [1,2], [2,3] => [15], [3] => [6,7,8], [4,9,11] => [3])

sv = map(length,keys(od))        # store length of keys for quicker calculations
maxmaxlen = sum(sv)              # maximum total elements in good key
for maxlen=1:maxmaxlen           # replace maxmaxlen with lower value if too slow
  @show maxlen
  gsets = Vector{Vector{Int}}()  # hold good sets of key _indices_
  for curlen=1:maxlen
    foreach(x->push!(gsets,x),
     (x for x in subsets(collect(1:n),curlen) if sum(sv[x])==maxlen))
  end
  # indmatrix is necessary to run through keys once in next loop
  indmatrix = zeros(Bool,length(od),length(gsets))
  for i=1:length(gsets)              for e in gsets[i]
      indmatrix[e,i] = true
    end
  end
  # gkeys is the vector of vecotrs of keys i.e. what we wanted to calculate
  gkeys = [Vector{Vector{Int}}() for i=1:length(gsets)]
  for (i,k) in enumerate(keys(od))
    for j=1:length(gsets)
      if indmatrix[i,j]
        push!(gkeys[j],k)
      end
    end
  end
  # do something with each set of good keys
  foreach(x->println(x),gkeys)
end
```

Is this more efficient that what you currently have? It would also be better to put the code in a function or turn it into a Julia task which produces the next keys set each iteration.

--- UPDATE ---

Using the answer about iterators from tasks in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41074729/3580870

An improved iterator-ified version is:

```
function keysubsets(n,d)
  Task() do
    od = OrderedDict(d)
    sv = map(length,keys(od))        # store length of keys for quicker calculations
    maxmaxlen = sum(sv)              # maximum total elements in good key
    for maxlen=1:min(n,maxmaxlen)    # replace maxmaxlen with lower value if too slow
      gsets = Vector{Vector{Int}}()  # hold good sets of key _indices_
      for curlen=1:maxlen
        foreach(x->push!(gsets,x),(x for x in subsets(collect(1:n),curlen) if sum(sv[x])==maxlen))
      end
      # indmatrix is necessary to run through keys once in next loop
      indmatrix = zeros(Bool,length(od),length(gsets))
      for i=1:length(gsets)              for e in gsets[i]
          indmatrix[e,i] = true
        end
      end
      # gkeys is the vector of vecotrs of keys i.e. what we wanted to calculate
      gkeys = [Vector{Vector{Int}}() for i=1:length(gsets)]
      for (i,k) in enumerate(keys(od))
        for j=1:length(gsets)
          if indmatrix[i,j]
            push!(gkeys[j],k)
          end
        end
      end
      # do something with each set of good keys
      foreach(x->produce(x),gkeys)
    end
  end
end
```

Which now enables iterating over all keysubsets up to combined size 4 in this way (after running the code from the other StackOverflow answer):

```
julia> nt2 = NewTask(keysubsets(4,od))
julia> collect(nt2)
10-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}:
 Array{Int64,1}[[1]]          
 Array{Int64,1}[[3]]          
 Array{Int64,1}[[2,3]]        
 Array{Int64,1}[[1],[3]]      
 Array{Int64,1}[[4,9,11]]     
 Array{Int64,1}[[1],[2,3]]    
 Array{Int64,1}[[2,3],[3]]    
 Array{Int64,1}[[1],[4,9,11]] 
 Array{Int64,1}[[3],[4,9,11]] 
 Array{Int64,1}[[1],[2,3],[3]]
```

(the definition of NewTask from the linked StackOverflow answer is necessary).